# Ubuntu 20.04 Gnome Tweaks not showing options for keyboard 3rd level character

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Using 20.04, I installed Gnome Tweaks to use the <kbd>L Alt</kbd> key in place of <kbd>R Alt</kbd> key to access 3<sup>rd</sup> level character in a modified keyboard (á, ç, ñ, é, è) by editing the `xbd/us` file.

When I go in Tweaks “Additional Layout options”, it gives me only 2 options:

- “Number 4 key when pressed in isolation”,
- “Number 9 key when pressed in isolation”.

In my other similar machine, I get a whole list of choices.

I reinstalled Tweaks a couple of times, to no avail.

The only difference between the 2 is that the other one have a regular US keyboard, not modified.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my question !
I just had to turn off "Show extended input sources" and bingo, I got the whole list for 3rd level character key.

Merry Christmas to all.

Comment: I could reproduce that behavior, but to me it appears to be a `gnome-tweaks` bug. Can't see a reason why the `show-all-sources` option would have anything to do with it.

Comment: Reported it as [bug #1906887](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1906887).